# Getting an error every time I Try to run npm install -g yo npm install -g generator-angular node is installed just fine

Tags: angularjs, node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

I am on osx yosmite and in my commandline im entering this:npm install -g yo.
And I keep getting this:
npm install -g generator-angulargenerator-angular@0.14.0 requires a peer of generator-karma@>=0.9.0 but none was installed.
I tried everything and still nothing.

Comment: have you tried this https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/1179 ?

Comment: Did you try installing karma generator ? and are you installing with sudo or just `npm install -g ....` ?